# Finding the error in an evaluation of the limit $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2} $

Tags: calculus, limits

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2}
&= \lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^x-1}{x^2} - \lim_{x\to0} \frac{1}{x} \\
&= \lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^x-1}{x}\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1}{x} - \lim_{x\to0} \frac{1}{x} \\ &= \lim_{x\to0} \frac{1}{x} - \lim_{x\to0} \frac{1}{x} \\
&= 0
\end{align}

Comment: The first equality already doesn't hold: Neither of the limits on the r.h.s. exist.

Comment: See \http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion

Comment: The error is, you can not use Limit Rules (substraction) when one of the limits does not exist.($\lim(A-B) \ne \lim(A) - \lim(B)$)

Comment: To expand on @Travis' comment: the method above is flawed, as you apply "normal" operations (sum, factorization, etc.) to quantities *that do not exist*: namely, $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{1}{x}$ -- in your proof, things go wrong as soon as you write this quantity). Basically, "anything can happen."

Comment: To illustrate one of the dangers of manipulating undefined quantities (here $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}$) as you did: from $1 = \frac{1+x}{x}-\frac{1}{x}$ (for any $x\neq 0$), you could write  $$1 = \lim_{x\to 0} (1+x)  \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{x} -  \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x} - \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x} = 0$$which definitely isn't *quite* right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error starts  here:

$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2} $$ $$\color{red}{\neq\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^x-1}{x^2} - \lim_{x\to0} \frac{1}{x} 
=\dots}$$

See [Basic Limit Laws](http://math.oregonstate.edu/home/programs/undergrad/CalculusQuestStudyGuides/SandS/lHopital/limit_laws.html)

---

**Hint:** Applaying L'Hopital twice gives $\frac 1 2 \lim\limits_{x\to 0} e^x$

Comment: i don't understand isnt $$ \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x} = 1$$ ?

Comment: Uhm, that limit is certainly $1$, but that is not the issue in your computation, Orenrevenge. The problem is what you did when splitting the given into separate limits. Try L'Hospital on your very given limit and you should be fine

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you tried to apply this proposition:

> If $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)=L_1$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)=L_2$, then $\lim_{x\to a} (f(x)+g(x)) = L_1+L_2$.

But in this case, $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}$ does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

The first claimed equality,
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^x-x-1}{x^2} \color{red}{\stackrel{\textrm{(false)}}{=}} \lim_{x\to0} \frac{e^x-1}{x^2} - \lim_{x\to0} \frac{1}{x} ,$$ already doesn't hold: Neither of the limits on its r.h.s. exist.

To evaluate the limit:

**Hint** Apply l'Hopital's Rule (twice) or expand $e^x$ in a Maclaurin series.